# How to setup chromedriver in jenkins for selenium-python script?

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using the following code to run my script in local machine

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import pytest
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import allure

class Test_main():

    @pytest.fixture()
    def test_setup(self):
        # instantiate browser
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:/Python/Sel_python/drivers/chromedriverv86/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)

        # terminate script
        yield
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.quit()
        print("Test completed")

##Remaining functions/test cases followed. Not adding the entire script here
```

I pushed this code onto git and then tried to run the same in jenkins using following build commands:

```
cd "D:\Python\Sel_python\Pytest"
pip install -r requirements.txt
pytest Test_Tracking_code_scripts.py -s -v
```

But then jenkins threw an error that chromedriver cannot be located. My questions are:

1. Do I need to upload `chromedriver.exe` as well into my git repository
2. Does jenkins have its own chrome browser? If yes how do I use it and what path has to be specified?

I am new to jenkins, please help me out here

Comment: Please clarify if Jenkins setup is in Windows or  Linux.
List of things needs to be taken care for this.
- OS
- Browser Version in System (to get appropriate driver)
- Path of Driver and Execution permission

Comment: @vjk: Its setup in Windows. Can you please help me out on the list of things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. My code was missing the chrome binary path. Adding the same as an `Options()` argument resolved the error. 
Sharing the updated patch of code:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import pytest
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import allure

class Test_main():

    @pytest.fixture()
    def test_setup(self):
        # initiating browser
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.binary_location=r"C:\Users\libin.thomas\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
        chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:/Python/Sel_python/drivers/chromedriver v86/chromedriver.exe",options=chrome_options)
       
        # terminate script
        yield
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.quit()
        print("Test completed")

#test cases followed below
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check chrome version in Jenkins system
   Download chrome driver based on Jenkins system from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
2. Copy the chrome driver to "C:/drivers/" in Jenkins server (As C driver is common to all windows system)
   update code as below

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:/Python/Sel_python/drivers/chromedriverv86/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

as

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/drivers/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Let me know if you face any issues with this.

**NOTE**:

1. In local system please move driver to "C:/driver" so that both remote and local system path is same.
2. If chrome version is updated in local or remote, please update chrome driver version i.e. **chromedriver.exe**

Comment: How do I check chrome version in Jenkins system?

Comment: Take RDP of remote windows system and you can check manually or you can try executing bat cmd from jenkins itself "reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon" /v version"

Comment: @LibinThomas are you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Thanks a ton for your support. I found the solution. Adding it as a comment